# How to change the CKEditor "Auto Save" message in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

[Here is screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/we7wa.png)

I want to change the "Auto Save" message of editor with custome message like "Saving your draft" etc...

Comment: And your problem is...?

Comment: I want to replace "Auto Save" message with my custom message. I am unable to find is property to do it.

Comment: It's this: https://github.com/w8tcha/CKEditor-AutoSave-Plugin right? Nothing in the docs which suggests you can set config to change the message. I suggest you ask the author for clarification and/or an enhancement request.

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide the code of your tries? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, How much research effort is expected https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users and How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve might be helpful to improve your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved it.

To replace the "Auto Save" message with your custom message:

1) Open the plugin's language file (this is within the CKEditor folder, wherever that is located in your website structure):

```
plugins/autosave/lang/en.js
```

2) Locate the entry

```
autoSaveMessage: 'Auto Saved'
```

3) Replace it with your custom message

```
autoSaveMessage: 'My custom message'
```

4) Save the file and re-load your editor.